# How the parent creates a pipe between each child and itself, and each child sends number of the words to the parent via the pipe

Tags: c, operating-system, filesystems, pipe, fork

The code I've written finds out the number of words in multiple text files by creating multiple processes with each process being responsible for one file to count its words.

What I want to do is using pipes to find out total number of words in all files.

So the parent should:

1. creates a pipe between the each child and itself so it can get the number of words from each child
2. reports the total number of words in all the files by adding the numbers received through pipes
3. checks the exit status of each child and prints out how that child
   exited

also let each child:

1. sends the number of the words to the parent via the pipe
2. send 0 as word count through the pipe to the parent if the file does
   not exist or any other error happens
3. returns/exits with 0 if it is successfull in opening the file and
   counting the words in that file, returns/exits with 1 if there is an
   error (e.g., file does not exist etc.)

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 100

pid_t getpid(void);
pid_t getppid(void);

char* itoa(int i, char b[]){
    char const digit[] = "0123456789";
    char* p = b;
    if(i<0){
        *p++ = '-';
        i *= -1;
    }
    int shifter = i;
    do{ //Move to where representation ends
        ++p;
        shifter = shifter/10;
    }while(shifter);
    *p = '\0';
    do{ //Move back, inserting digits as u go
        *--p = digit[i%10];
        i = i/10;
    }while(i);
    return b;
}
int countWords(char * fp, int pid) {
   FILE * file;
   int words = 0;
   char word[MAX_CHAR];
   //execute this function only if child process of parent, no gradchild is allowed to execute this function!
   if (pid == getppid()) {
      file = fopen(fp, "r");
      if (file == NULL) {
         return -1;
      }
      //find string in the file and count the words.
      while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF) {
         words++;
      }
      return words;
   } else {
      return -1;
   }
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * arvg[]) {
   //if invalid arguments
   if (argc < 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: INVALID ARGUMENTS");
      exit(-1);
   }

   int count = 0, pid, ppid, status, totalwords;
   
   int result = -1;
   int fd[2];
   char string[100];
   char readbuffer[80];
   int *write_fd = &fd[1];
   int *read_fd = &fd[0];
   result = pipe(fd);
   if(-1 == result){
     perror("pipe");
     return -1;
   }
   //creates (argc - 1) child processes using fork()
   pid = (int) malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(int));
   //parent pid
   ppid = getpid();

   //each child process to count the number of words in each file
   for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      //child process
      pid = fork();
      if( pid == -1){
          perror("failed to fork");
          return -1;
      }else if (pid == 0) {
         // call a function to count the number of words in file arvg[i]
         int words = countWords(arvg[i], ppid);
         close(*read_fd);
         if (words >= 0) {
            printf("Child process pid_%d for %s :number of words is %d\n", i, arvg[i], words);
            //I don't know how to write int into the pipe,so below might be wrong
            write(*write_fd, words, 1);
          
            return 0;
         } else if (words == -1) {
            printf("Child process pid_%d for %s :does not exists\n", i, arvg[I]);
            //I don't know how to write int into the pipe,so below might be wrong
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, words, 1);
            
            exit(1);
         }
      } else {
         close(*write_fd);

         //and I have no idea how to read int from pipes
         read(*read_fd, &readbuffer, 1);

         totalwords += ???
         close(*read_fd);
         //Wait until all child processes exit/return
         if (ppid == getpid()) {
            wait( & status);
         }
         //inspect their exit codes, WEXITSTATUS = return code when child exits
         if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 1) {
            count++;
         }
      }
   }
   printf("Main process created %d child processes to count words in %d files\n", argc - 1, argc - 1);
   printf("Total words is %d", totalwords);
   printf("%d files have been counted sucessfully!\n", argc - 1 - count);
   printf("%d files did not exist.\n", count);

   return 0;
}```

Can someone help me to figure out this? I don't really know how to achieve my goal with pipe.
````

Comment: You posted your goal and your attempt, but not the specific problem you're having.

Comment: I failed when I was using the pipe to read and write things. In the child process, I closed fd[0] and wrote a number of words, and in parent process I closed fd[0] and read the number of words, but there's a segmentation fault.

Comment: I don't see where you are reading or writing to or from the pipe. I would check out the example here https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe

Answer (score 0):

found some issues with the code. I fixed them for you (however, I would have done the same thing slight differently)

1. reading and writing int from a pipe is pretty straight forward, just typecast correctly while reading or writing to an int.
2. malloc to a pid was not necessary. Also malloc returns a pointer and should have been typecasted with (int*)
3. always add the right includes while using calls. Manual page or reading about the calls while trying to understand the parameters passed and return values is extremely useful.

Enough said, here is your working code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    
    #define MAX_CHAR 100
    
    pid_t getpid(void);
    pid_t getppid(void);
    
    char* itoa(int i, char b[]){
        char const digit[] = "0123456789";
        char* p = b;
        if(i<0){
            *p++ = '-';
            i *= -1;
        }
        int shifter = i;
        do{ //Move to where representation ends
            ++p;
            shifter = shifter/10;
        }while(shifter);
        *p = '\0';
        do{ //Move back, inserting digits as u go
            *--p = digit[i%10];
            i = i/10;
        }while(i);
        return b;
    }
    int countWords(char * fp, int pid) {
       FILE * file;
       int words = 0;
       char word[MAX_CHAR];
       //execute this function only if child process of parent, no gradchild is allowed to execute this function!
       if (pid == getppid()) {
          file = fopen(fp, "r");
          if (file == NULL) {
             return -1;
          }
          //find string in the file and count the words.
          while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF) {
             words++;
          }
          return words;
       } else {
          return -1;
       }
       return 0;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char * arvg[]) {
       //if invalid arguments
       if (argc < 2) {
          fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: INVALID ARGUMENTS");
          exit(-1);
       }
    
       int count = 0, pid, ppid, status, totalwords = 0;
       
       int result = -1;
       int fd[2];
       char string[100];
       char readbuffer[80];
       int *write_fd = &fd[1];
       int *read_fd = &fd[0];
       int recvd = 0;
       result = pipe(fd);
       if(-1 == result){
         perror("pipe");
         return -1;
       }
       //creates (argc - 1) child processes using fork()
       //pid = (int) malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(int));
       //parent pid
       ppid = getpid();
    
       //each child process to count the number of words in each file
       for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
          //child process
          pid = fork();
          if( pid == -1){
              perror("failed to fork");
              return -1;
          }else if (pid == 0) {
              printf ("%d child running \n", i);
             // call a function to count the number of words in file arvg[i]
             int words = countWords(arvg[i], ppid);
             close(*read_fd);
             if (words >= 0) {
                printf("Child process pid_%d for %s :number of words is %d\n", i, arvg[i], words);
                //I don't know how to write int into the pipe,so below might be wrong
                write(*write_fd, (void *)&words, 1);
              
                return 0;
             } else if (words == -1) {
                printf("Child process pid_%d for %s :does not exists\n", i, arvg[i]);
                //I don't know how to write int into the pipe,so below might be wrong
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, (void *)&words, 1);
                
                exit(1);
             }
          } else {
             close(*write_fd);
    
             //and I have no idea how to read int from pipes
             read(*read_fd, (void*)&recvd, 1);
    
             totalwords += recvd;
             printf("recvd %d \n", totalwords);
             close(*read_fd);
             //Wait until all child processes exit/return
             if (ppid == getpid()) {
                wait( & status);
             }
             //inspect their exit codes, WEXITSTATUS = return code when child exits
             if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 1) {
                count++;
             }
          }
       }
       printf("Main process created %d child processes to count words in %d files\n", argc - 1, argc - 1);
       printf("Total words is %d\n", totalwords);
       printf("%d files have been counted sucessfully!\n", argc - 1 - count);
       printf("%d files did not exist.\n", count);
    
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I ran your code and there's no error, but the output is wrong, I have several files with different number of words, but for each child process it only writes the number of words of the first file. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: added a new answer <https://stackoverflow.com/a/62832264/13876104> . Please try that and let me know. I think you need to look at fork() in a loop. Also please understand child process has a free run after the fork, so we need to protect everything else from it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first time around, I did not focus on the algo. I fixed all of it. The problem is forking in a loop and reading and writing it would lead to wrong results. Moreover, Parent needs to look for EOF to ensure all read has happened. Anyways, Here is the code that should work

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    
    #define MAX_CHAR 100
    
    pid_t getpid(void);
    pid_t getppid(void);
    
    char* itoa(int i, char b[]){
        char const digit[] = "0123456789";
        char* p = b;
        if(i<0){
            *p++ = '-';
            i *= -1;
        }
        int shifter = i;
        do{ //Move to where representation ends
            ++p;
            shifter = shifter/10;
        }while(shifter);
        *p = '\0';
        do{ //Move back, inserting digits as u go
            *--p = digit[i%10];
            i = i/10;
        }while(i);
        return b;
    }
    
    // count word from file provided
    int countWords(char * fp, int pid) {
       FILE * file;
       int words = 0;
       char word[MAX_CHAR];
       //execute this function only if child process of parent, no gradchild is allowed to execute this function!
       if (pid == getppid()) {
          file = fopen(fp, "r");
          if (file == NULL) {
             return -1;
          }
          //find string in the file and count the words.
          while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF) {
             words++;
          }
          return words;
       } else {
          return -1;
       }
       return 0;
    }
    
    //do everything related to child here in this function
    void child_process(int write_fd, char *filename, int ppid)
    {
        // call a function to count the number of words in file argv[i]
        printf("counting words of %s\n", filename);
        int words = countWords(filename, ppid);
        if (words >= 0) {
            printf("Child process pid for %s :number of words is %d\n", filename, words);
            write(write_fd, (void *)&words, 1);
            close(write_fd);
            exit(0);
        } else if (words == -1) {
            printf("Child process pid for %s :does not exist\n", filename);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, (void *)&words, 1);
            close(write_fd);
            exit(1);
        }
        return;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
       //if invalid arguments
       if (argc < 2) {
          fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: INVALID ARGUMENTS");
          exit(-1);
       }
    
       int pid = 0;
       int ppid = 0;
       int totalwords = 0;
       int fd[2] = {0};
       int write_fd = 0;
       int read_fd = 0;
       int recvd = 0;
    
       // open a pipe
       if(-1 == pipe(fd)){
         perror("pipe");
         return -1;
       }
    
       // assign write_fd and read_fd
       write_fd = fd[1];
       read_fd = fd[0];
    
       //parent pid
       ppid = getpid();
    
       //each child process to count the number of words in each file
       pid = fork();
       for (int i = 0; i < argc-1; i++)
       {
           //child process
           if (pid == 0) {
               close(read_fd);
               child_process(write_fd, argv[i+1], ppid);
               break;
           } else {
               pid = fork();
           }
    
       }
    
       // don't let child run beyond this point
       if (pid == 0) {
           exit(0);
       }
    
       // parent only code
       if (pid > 0)
       {
           close(write_fd);
           while (read(read_fd, (void*)&recvd, 1) > 0) 
           {
               wait(NULL);
               totalwords += recvd;
           }
           close(read_fd);
       } 
       printf("Main process created %d child processes to count words in %d files\n", argc - 1, argc - 1);
       printf("Total words is %d\n", totalwords);
       printf("%d files have been counted sucessfully!\n", argc - 1);
    }
```

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!